# Creating dataproc cluster from a template

Tags: cluster-computing, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

How to change the cluster image version while creating a dataproc cluster from the existing cluster's template i.e. the yaml file?
Here my existing cluster is having an older version of dataproc image but I want to use the latest image in the new cluster. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change image version in YAML file, you should set or change it in the `imageVersion` field:

```yaml
config:
  # . . .
  softwareConfig:
    # . . .
    imageVersion: <IMAGE_VERSION>
  # . . .
```

Comment: Thanks, Igor. but how can I get the proper build number i.e. dataproc-1-4-deb9-20190313-000000-rc02(this image version is from my current cluster). Do I need to provide the image version in the above format only ?

Comment: This is `imageUri`, not an image version, you can delete it from the template and specify just an `imageVersion` as shown in my answer. For example, `1.4-debian9`

Comment: Hi Igor, I more question
Is it possible to move my current cluster configuration and my all existing nodes to a new cluster?

Comment: No, you will need to delete and recreate new cluster with configuration that you need. The simplest will be [export](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/export)/[import](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/import) route.